# Javascript changes date format when concatenating it in string

Tags: javascript, date

```js
const date = new Date();

date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);

console.log(date); // 2018-03-03T23:10:24.063Z 
console.log(date + 'hello'); // Sat Mar 03 2018 15:10:59 GMT-0800 (PST)hello
```

What's going on here? How can I use the `date` value without formatting it to be human readable? Thanks!

Comment: The console is stringifying your date differently depending on how you print it. You can use a Date however you like, see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toJSON()` is your friend (more often than not):

```js
const date = new Date();

date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);

console.log(date);
console.log(date.toString());
console.log(`${date.toJSON()}hello`);
```

Internally, `Date.prototype.toJSON()` uses `Date.prototype.toISOString()`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON

When concatenating a `date` object with a `string`, internally `Date.prototype.toString()` is being called - and that creates the output you do not want in your case.

> The `Date` object overrides the `toString()` method of the `Object` object; it does not inherit `Object.prototype.toString()`. For `Date` objects, the `toString()` method returns a `string` representation of the object.
>
> The `toString()` method always returns a `string` representation of the date in *American English*.
>
> JavaScript calls the `toString()` method automatically when a `date` is to be represented as a text value or when a date is referred to in a string concatenation.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing that aligns the output of `console.log` with the output of `toJSON`, or that says `console.log` should call `.toString()` or `.toISOString()` on a `Date` object.  I've requested it here: https://github.com/whatwg/console/issues/132

Comment: Well, as long as that's only a problem for console output, it's not too big of an issue - other than frequently producing SO questions. Good point nonetheless!

Comment: Yep.  Causes headaches, but hopefully not much more than that. ;)

Comment: If ISO format is required, then *toISOString* seems to be a much more semantic option.

Comment: so console.log() calls ```.toISOString()``` and when concating a string which includes a date ```toString()``` is called is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

> 2018-03-03T23:10:24.063Z

This is [`date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), so `date.toISOString() + 'hello'`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know the logic for Javascript changing the formatting when concatenating in a string? I don't really like it :|

Comment: @Antoine - It's not changing any format.  It's just that `console.log` on a `Date` object is not defined by any spec whatsoever, and thus varies across implementations.  (In the first log statement, you are logging a `Date`.  In the second one, you're logging a `String`)

Comment: Wondering where the selection between `toString` and `toISOString` is being made.  Switch in `console.log()` perhaps

Comment: @Tibrogargan I'm not sure that I understand your question, but how stuff is logged is up to the [Printer](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer) implementation. Nothing requires that `toString` is called.

Comment: @Tibrogargan check the answer below, internally toString() is called 

Comment: @Tibrogargan - it's not a switch per se, it's just that it differs in the underlying implementations, because it's not standardized.  I've asked for it to be, here: https://github.com/whatwg/console/issues/132

Comment: @MattJohnson On the face of it, that's not correct.  The `+` operator in JavaScript is converting the date to a string through `Object.toString` and getting the expected result.  Something in the `console.log` call stack however is aware of the `Date` class and selecting `toISOString` as opposed to just using the default `Object.toString`

Comment: Yes, agreed.  We are saying the same thing.  The behavior is defined for concatenation, but not for logging.